# MySQLdb.OperationalError: and django.db.utils.OperationalError 1054, "Unknown column" after field rename in Django and MySql

Tags: mysql, django, rename, django-migrations, operationalerror

I have django app that is connected to MySql database.
I have renamed the field in models.py and succesfuly ran the migration. (the name alteration is written in migrations file)

I have also manually altered the field in the MySql, so it's called the same as in models.py;

After trying to run new migrations i get MySQLdb.OperationalError: and django.db.utils.OperationalError1054, "Unknown column 'oldName' in 'mysql_tableName'"
(oldName being field name before altering filed, mysql_tableName the name of the table as it is in the MySQL database)

What should I do?
Why does django db connection have oldName of the field?

inspectdb shows the new field name in the output; when checking mysql, there is new name of the field, running the sql command in db (SELECT newName FROM mysql_tableName) works fine.

EDIT: Ok, so my problem i guess was, that because the Meta atribute was set to Managed = True in models.py so the app was probably trying to change the db field but couldn't find it, as i renamed it manually in the db; After I renamed the mysql field to original; the migration took place without error, the field was also renamed in the db.

Comment: Is there `db_column` attribute for the field in the model?

Comment: No, field names are the same in model and MySql

Comment: can you share your fieldnames before and after the change

Comment: migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='k1210npk',
            old_name='to',
            new_name='leto',
        )
Error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'to' in 'k12_10_npk'")

Model have db_table attribute in class Meta (db_table = 'k12_10_npk')

Comment: What is the name of the field in the model itself? Did you create the migration by hand or did you use makemigrations?

Comment: it's "leto" (this is the new name);

Comment: I used makemigrations and migrate for field renaming; now the problem arises when running migrate command (trying to make new changes)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Mohamed. So my problem i guess was, that the Meta atribute was set to Managed = True in models.py; and the app was probably trying to change the db field but couldn't find as i renamed it manually in the db; After I renamed the mysql field to original; the migration toop place without error, the field was also renamed in the db.